# How to convert array into object with out zeroth position

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I'm trying to convert an array into an object

```
"loanArray" : [
   {
    "recordID" : "LKOCH123",
    "date" : "20221206",
    "productId" : "21023"
   }
]
```

I've converted this into an Object using Object.assign like below:

```
let loanObj= Object.assign({}, loanArray)
```

```
"loanObj" : {
   "0": {
    "recordID" : "LKOCH123",
    "date" : "20221206",
    "productId" : "21023"
   }
}
```

However, I want to remove that "0" position in my object, and the expected is below:
please help to achieve this structure.

```
"loanObj" : {
    "recordID" : "LKOCH123",
    "date" : "20221206",
    "productId" : "21023"
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
const loanArray = [{recordID: 'LKOCH123', date: '20221206', productId: '21023'}]

const [loanObj] = loanArray

console.log(loanObj)
```